# NodeJS dotenv - Not reading string value properly

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to us `dotenv` (https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) in nodeJS to store the client secret value for an oauth server I'm using.

My `.env` file looks like the following:

`clientSecret=imU86A3oPiZlyOhZybShraP377ers0MvowBaizEQ`

Within the NodeJS file, I have the following:

```
passport.use(new PasswordGrantStrategy({
    tokenURL: 'WEBSITE_ADDRESS',
    clientID: "2",
    clientSecret: process.env.clientSecret,
    grantType: "password",

},
```

The problem is that I get a `Token Error` but, if I change it the following:

```
passport.use(new PasswordGrantStrategy({
    tokenURL: 'WEBSITE_ADDRESS',
    clientID: "2",
    clientSecret: "imU86A3oPiZlyOhZybShraP377ers0MvowBaizEQ",
    grantType: "password",

},
```

This then works perfectly fine. I don't understand what the problem could be and I've tried to cast it as a string but no such luck.

The values are both matching and I'm printing them out and they are both the same.

Comment: How you load .env file? And how you start script?

Comment: you can console.log it above passport.use line and see what value it holds

Comment: so what is the value of `process.env.clientSecret` ?

Answer (score 4):

Use a **backtick** to wrap the string value and your life will be a breeze!

```
clientSecret=`imU86A3oPiZlyOhZybShraP377ers0MvowBaizEQ`
```

Comment: Only thing I found that worked in my environment. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have dotenv installed
Make sure you config *dotenv* as early as possible in your app

```
require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname + '/.env'});
```

note: good idea to use the *path* parameter in some setups, for example if using a debugger otherwise dotenv may not find and load the .env file.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set dynamically the environment value in you app variable

```
 for(const [keyObj, valObj] of Object.entries(data)){
     for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(valObj)){
         app.set(key.toLocaleLowerCase(), value);
     }
 }
```